# Padding in a vec3f array in WebGPU memory layout

Tags: javascript, graphics-programming, memory-efficiency, wgsl, webgpu

I'm trying to write a WGSL structs parser (sort of webgpu-utils thing). In order to better understand the memory layout, I'm using [wgsl offset computer](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/resources/wgsl-offset-computer.html) as a helper.

Having the next struct:

```
struct A {
  a: array<vec3f, 3>,
  b: f32
};
```

The layout given by the mentioned tool looks like:
[image]

I'm struggling with the difference between the graphical representation and the `AInfo` object. In the graphics, it is clearly seen that each item in the `array<vec3f, 3>` has alignment padding of 4 bytes and the offsets for three items are 0, 16 and 32 respectively. On the other hand, in the `AInfo` object the offset of the array `a` is zero and the length is 48 bytes, which implies the bytes arrangement in the array is consequent. Referencing to the graphics, I would expect the object representation to be sort of:

```js
const AInfo = {
  a: [
    {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 0, length: 4}, // 16 bytes
    {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 16, length: 4}, // 16 bytes
    {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 32, length: 4}, // 16 bytes
  ],
  b: {type: Float32Array, byteOffset: 48, length: 1}
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, where do you see a length of 36 bytes reported? I see it says the length is 12 entries, times 4 bytes per entry would be a byte length of 48. Is there a different report you're looking at?

Comment: @DMGregory, yes, I don't know why I wrote 36. You are absolutely correct. Putting that aside, by the given output I need to know how to manage the per-item padding in the array by myself, for there are no inner offsets to the array. Is that correct?

Comment: From what I know, the layout matches the picture, with 4 bytes of padding at the end of each vector. Do you have reason to doubt that picture, or evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @DMGregory nope, it took me some time to understand I just messed up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My confusion was regarding inner padding of data passed to the `array<vec3f>`. It is now clear, that in order for it to work correctly, the data should be padded:

```js
[
  1, 2, 3, 
  4, 5, 6, 
  7, 8, 9
] -> 
[
  1, 2, 3, 0, 
  4, 5, 6, 0,
  7, 8, 9, 0
]
```